# What does it mean to be an Instance of the Azure Active Directory?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, cloud

Microsoft says, "In Azure Active Directory a tenant is an instance of Azure Active Directory that an organization receives when it signs up for a cloud application like Microsoft 365."

Could anyone explain what it means for a tenant to be an instance of the Azure Active Directory?

I know that an instance is basically a virtual machine. However, I'm failing to see how that definition applies in this particular context.

Comment: *I know that an instance is basically a virtual machine.* -> not in this context. Here it means it is a dedicated Azure Active Directory tenant (instance) for your organization

Answer (score 1):

**In your context, Instance of Azure Active Directory means Azure tenant.**

I agree with @[Peter Bons](https://stackoverflow.com/users/932728/peter-bons), Azure tenant is a dedicated and trusted instance of Azure AD.

- Tenant refers to a **single instance** of Azure Active Directory.
- Please note that tenant will be **automatically created** when your organization signs up for a Microsoft cloud service subscription.
- To make it simple, you can consider it as **parent group** that includes users and groups along with the access control to application and resources.
- A tenant is associated with a **single identity** and can have one or several subscriptions.
- Based on your requirement, you can have **single tenant** or **multitenant**.
- Every tenant is linked to a **single Azure AD instance**, which is shared with all tenant's subscriptions.
- Azure AD Tenants are globally **unique** and have scopes with a domain name ending with ‘onmicrosoft.com’ and has a **`Tenant ID`** in the form of UUID/GUID.

For more in detail, please **refer** below links:

[Understanding Tenants, Subscriptions, Regions and Geographies in Azure – siliconvalve](https://blog.siliconvalve.com/2018/08/27/understanding-tenants-subscriptions-regions-and-geographies-in-azure/)

[What is Azure Active Directory Tenant and How to create (azurelib.com)](https://azurelib.com/azure-active-directory-tenant/)

Comment: Hey @AdeTalabi! had it solved your problem else you can share more details so I can troubleshoot?