# Difference between Azure AAD Tenant & Organization

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have come across many articles discussing concept of AAD, Organization & tenant -- it's pretty confusing. From what I understand at the root there is an 'organization' which has exactly one AAD and it can have several subscriptions. But I have read in some articles that an organization can have one or more tenants, isn't organization itself a 'tenant', not sure why it's being called out separately ? And am I correct in that name of the AAD for an organization will be .onmicrosoft.com ?

Comment: Related post - [What is the difference between an Azure tenant and Azure subscription?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47307368/465053)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenant is more technical term for me, `[tenant-name].onmicrosoft.com` - is your Azure AD tenant or just an instance of Azure AD.

Organisation is more juridical or commercial term for me. Organisation can have as many tenants as it wants, it is an object associated with person or business unit who will pay for everything, a container for all bought tenants, services, licenses, subscriptions, etc.

For example, you can have test and production Azure AD tenants under the same organisation.

For more details of different options:

1. [Subscriptions, licenses, accounts, and tenants for Microsoft's cloud offerings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/enterprise/subscriptions-licenses-accounts-and-tenants-for-microsoft-cloud-offerings)
2. [Azure enterprise scaffold: Prescriptive subscription governance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/cloud-adoption-framework/reference/azure-scaffold)[enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/cloud-adoption-framework/reference/azure-scaffold)
3. [Azure CSP overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-solution-provider/overview/azure-csp-overview)

Comment: Thanks, trying to understand your answer. So lets say we have an organization called 'mycompany' -- it has multiple tenants 1) mycompany-it.onmicrosoft.com 2) mycompany-hr.onmicrosoft.com 3) mycompany-operations.onmicrosoft.com. Each of the 3 tenants has its own dedicated AD associated with it. In fact the 3 items I listed are actually names of Azure Directories right? Does this description sounds right? And also, I wonder, if they have subscriptions for billing separation, what is the use of having separate tenant.

Comment: Separate tenants are sometimes used to separate environments. Apps that you develop may require the ability to access user data, and using the production tenant during development would be a bad idea. It can also be for separation of billing so that different branches in different countries can handle those on their own. But it does make it more complex to develop apps for use by the company, since those apps must be made multi-tenant, but then only accept those tenants.

Comment: @Dhiraj usually you have only one production tenant per organisation, like mycompany.onmicrosoft.com, so everybody inside organisation can communicate, find each other and have rights on shared resources if needed. You need separate tenant in case of tests/development as juunas example, or in case if you do not want to mix some critical identities to access to some critical data/applications, i.e. usually there are a company tenant + comany's R&D department tenant, it protects from human errors when somebody from R&D accidentally could share a critical data with someone outside of R&D

Comment: @Dhiraj also you can have a situation when company has acquired another company which already has a tenant, depends of level of collaboration they could be in the merging process or stay separately

Comment: @Dhiraj from billing point of view, Cloud products licenses are attached to Tenant level and not to Subscription, i.e. you have bought 100 Office 365 accounts they will be associated with a tenant, Subscriptions separate only Azure usage costs