# Azure tenant is a directory?

Tags: azure

I am trying to understand why several lectures say that an Azure tenat is a directory ([example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47307368/what-is-the-difference-between-an-azure-tenant-and-azure-subscription)). According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-whatis) an Azure tenant is a trusted instance of the Azure AD, and, again, according that docs a Azure AD is a service a not a directory. Could you help me to understand why several lectures say the Azure tenant is a directory if docs say that is an instance of a service, please?

Answer (score 2):

I think what is confusing is that the word directory has several meanings. When directory is used in this context it means an Azure Active Directory instance. An instance of the Azure Active Directory service is a tenant. If you created multiple Azure ADs in your Azure Portal you would have multiple instances therefore you would have multiple tenants or as some would say directories. I hope that clarifies it a little.

Comment: Though in my opinion you can't really create AAD tenants _in a subscription_. Subscriptions are placed under an AAD tenant.