# Azure tenants, AD and subscriptions

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am a little bit confused about Azure tenants, AD and subscriptions.

Imagine a customer starting from scratch.
Can I say that the first step is creating (subscribing) a tenant?
After creating a tenant, is there a default AD? Can they create other ADs inside the same tenamt?
Can they create more subscriprions for a single tenant?
Given they can, can a subscription be associated to one or more ADs?

Is there any page or document describing the concepts and the design of Azure components (tenants, AD and subscriptions)?
Regards
marius

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between an Azure tenant and Azure subscription?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47307368/what-is-the-difference-between-an-azure-tenant-and-azure-subscription)

Comment: Remember 1 Azure AD = 1 Tenant.  Azure AD is basically [Directory service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_service) which is managed by Microsoft Cloud. Active Directory is Microsoft specific implementation of LDAP.

Answer (score 0):

When you signed up to Azure using a Microsoft account, then you will get Azure with a Default Directory. A tenant is associated with a single identity (person, company, or organization) and can own one or several subscriptions. Single tenant can have multiple Active directories, but a single directory can only have 1 tenant.

There is similar [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47307368/what-is-the-difference-between-an-azure-tenant-and-azure-subscription) which can help you in understanding more.